# Open svg vector saved in .XML with gwt

Tags: java, xml, svg, gwt

I am working on a gwt based application now I want to open an svg image in popup panel of gwt. But the svg I'm getting from server is in a file of .XML format. I have checked lib-gwt-svg examples and examples referring to mime type image/svg+ XML.
But those are  not helping.

Comment: I don't get what your problem is. SVG **is** XML (like HTML **is** XML): `popup.add(new HTML("<svg height='100' width='100'><circle cx='50' cy='50' r='40' stroke='black' stroke-width='3' fill='red' /></svg>"));`

Comment: I'm getting a file from server which is a XML document having svg as a root tag. Now I want to create a pop-up panel in gwt and display that file as an svg image in popup.

Comment: Just try: `popup.add(new HTML(--file-content--));`.

Comment: Yeah it worked thankyou

Comment: How can I add a close button with it. I tried with close handler but its not working

Comment: Well, that should be posted as a new question. Please, include information whether you need a close button as a part of SVG or do you need to hook up on a popup close event.

Comment: Hook up on popup close event